# Add confirmation pop-up to admin form "Save" button

Tags: admin, javascript, forms, adminform, form-validation

I have custom module which adds admin form. There is a button "Save" in the form container that saves the entire form and adds some data to the database.

[image]

I would like to avoid situation that user accidentally clicks the button.
How to add a javascript to the button that would display (on button click) a pop-up window with text like:

***"Are you sure you want save? Yes/No"***?

If user clicks ***"Yes"***, then the default action for the "Save" button will be triggered and form will be submitted. If user clicks ***"No"*** then nothing happens. This will prevent accidentally saving the form.

Is there anything like this available in magento admin forms? If not, how to add this feature to my form?

```
class Super_Awesome_Block_Adminhtml_Example_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_blockGroup = 'awesome';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_example';

        $this->_addButton(
            'my_button_save',
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Save'),
                'class' => 'save',
            ),
            100
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may help you

```
 $base_fieldset->addField(
                'your_btn', 'button', array(
            'name' => 'your_btn',
            'label' => Mage::helper('testmodule')->__(
                    'Click on folowing link to test popup Dialog:'
            ),
            'value' => $this->helper('testmodule')->__('Test popup dialog >>'),
            'class' => 'form-button',
            'onclick' => 'javascript:openMyPopup()'
                )
        );
        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
        parent::_prepareForm();
```

Then in layout file

```
<?php echo $this->getFormInitScripts() ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openMyPopup() {
        var url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('adminhtml/dashboard/index') ?>?';
        if ($('browser_window') &amp;&amp; typeof(Windows) != 'undefined') {
            Windows.focus('browser_window');
            return;
        }
        var dialogWindow = Dialog.info(null, {
            closable:true,
            resizable:false,
            draggable:true,
            className:'magento',
            windowClassName:'popup-window',
            title:'Test popup Dialog',
            top:50,
            width:300,
            height:150,
            zIndex:1000,
            recenterAuto:false,
            hideEffect:Element.hide,
            showEffect:Element.show,
            id:'browser_window',
            url:url,
            onClose:function (param, el) {
                alert('onClose');
            }
        });
    }
    function closePopup() {
        Windows.close('browser_window');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but your example is for form button inside custom fieldset, but my button is in the form main container, not in custom fieldset. Also, I don't have any template file to add that javascript. i don't quite understand this example.

Comment: @TBI, where i need to add this javascript file,

Answer (score 0):

Magento gives you default validation process. You can use it. In your Grid.php,

For example you need validation for email field, So

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
  {
      $this->addColumn('email', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('sendsms')->__('Email'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'email',
          'required'  => true,
      ));

[...]

}
```

Here  `'required'  => true,` it enables validation for you..!

Thats it ..Cheers..!

Comment: I edited my question to explain better what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I have to do this for promo (coupon) module in admin. So I am writing how to do this.

Module file:

```
<config>
<modules>
    <NS_Promo>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Adminhtml/>
        </depends>
    </NS_Promo>
</modules>
```

app/local/NS/Promo/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ns_Promo>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Ns_Promo>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <promo_quote_edit>NS_Promo_Block_Quote_Edit</promo_quote_edit>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/local/NS/Promo/Block/Quote/Edit

```
    class NS_Promo_Block_Quote_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Promo_Quote_Edit
{

    /**
     * Initialize form
     * Add "Save and Continue" button
     * 
     * Murtaza: added a js function to confirm 
     * if admin user wants to add promo withoud coupon
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_updateButton('save', 'onclick', 'return confirmFunction(\'save\');');
        $this->_updateButton('save_and_continue_edit', 'onclick', 'return confirmFunction(\'savencontinue\');');
    }
}
```

js confirmFunction is:

```
function confirmFunction(type) {
     if (!window.confirm('<?php echo Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('message?') ?>')) {
            return false;
        }

        if (type == 'save') {
            editForm.submit();
        } else {
            editForm.submit($('edit_form').action + 'back/edit/');
        }
}
```

hope this will help someone :)